# Unable to import pylab?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I've installed numpy/scipy/matplotlib on Snow Leopard with python 2.6.  Importing pylab does not seem to be working..  Upon calling 'import pylab', I get the following:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 216, in <module>
    from matplotlib import mpl  # pulls in most modules
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl.py", line 2, in <module>
    from matplotlib import axis
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 10, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1339, in <module>
    _rebuild()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1326, in _rebuild
    fontManager = FontManager()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1004, in __init__
    self.ttffiles = findSystemFonts(paths) + findSystemFonts()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 343, in findSystemFonts
    for f in get_fontconfig_fonts(fontext):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 301, in get_fontconfig_fonts
    output = pipe.communicate()[0]
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 683, in communicate
    stdout = self.stdout.read()
```

What gives?  Is pylab expecting something I don't have?  It seems to be unable to read something, but I don't really understand what that is..

Comment: Eh? There's no actual error there. Did you paste the whole traceback?

Comment: That's the whole traceback.  It hangs until I keyboard interrupt it.  Maybe I'll let it sit for a while and see if anything happens.  Is this module supposed to take long to import?

Comment: do you have freetype 1.4 installed? it is required for matplotlib.

Comment: Same problem four years later, which makes me wonder whether this is really a library that should be used...

Answer (score 5):

Just wait.  The problem is that fc-list takes a long time to run the first time through, and so it looks like it's hung; but if you wait 2-3 minutes it will finish and then run more quickly thereafter.

I ran fc-list at the command line as root, which presumably initialized a cache of some sort; not sure that's necessary, but it worked!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
from pylab import *
```

If pylab is successfully installed in your python env. There won't raise any error.